# Default Checkbutton Selected Status to True

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set the initial state of a checkbox to "selected"

In my gui, I have the following snippet of code that works

```
testFrame = Frame(bigFrame)
testFrame.pack(fill=BOTH)
testLabel = Label(testFrame,
         text="Start from previously saved bias point?")
testLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
testChckbttn = Checkbutton(testFrame)
testChckbttn.pack(side=LEFT)
testchckbttn.select()
```

However, when I introduce a variable "testvar", it no longer works.  I.e. the box is unselected at the start regardless.

```
testFrame = Frame(bigFrame)
testFrame.pack(fill=BOTH)
testLabel = Label(testFrame,
         text="Start from previously saved bias point?")
testLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
testvar = IntVar()
testChckbttn = Checkbutton(testFrame, variable=testvar)
testChckbttn.pack(side=LEFT)
testchckbttn.select()
```

Is the testvar messing up .select() ?  Is there a way to insist the box is selected by default?

[edit] - I have removed the incomplete code.  Here is the simplest complete code that reproduces the error for me.  I.e. This code is supposed to produce a tick box that is selected by default, but instead it is unselected.

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Button, BOTH, LEFT, Label, \
                    Checkbutton, IntVar

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Test")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        bigFrame = Frame(self)
        bigFrame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        testFrame = Frame(bigFrame)
        testFrame.pack(fill=BOTH)
        testLabel = Label(testFrame,
                                  text="Test")
        testLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        testvar = IntVar()
        testChckbttn = Checkbutton(testFrame,variable=testvar)
        testChckbttn.pack(side=LEFT)
        testChckbttn.select()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What platform are you running this on, and what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64 bit.

Comment: I don't understand your update. You keep posting code that has errors, so I am pretty certain it's not really your code. That, or you're simply ignoring the errors it is throwing.

Comment: I kept trying to return to a new line but stackExchange interpreted it as a request to submit.  Sorry.

(It did it again) I have edited the question to include the simplest complete code that reproduces the error for me.  I.e. If you copy the above verbatim and run it with python, it produces an unselected box when I want a selected box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to make `testvar` an instance variable:

```
self.testvar = IntVar()
testChckbttn = Checkbutton(testFrame,variable=self.testvar)
testChckbttn.pack(side=LEFT)
testChckbttn.select()
```

As it is, `testvar` is being updated on select() (ie, `print testvar.get()` after select() prints 1), but for some reason the `testChckbttn` object isn't visibly updating.

Making it an instance variable will help in the long run, though, as it will now be available in other methods of the class, as there probably won't be much use for it within the `initUI` method.

Comment: The "some reason" is exactly what you said -- the variable is local to the method, so when the method exits the variable gets garbage-collected. You are create that the proper solution is to make it an instance variable.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. This might be a stupid question, but why does testChckbttn (and testFrame, or any other local variable) hang around after the method exits? Is it because of their parent widgets?

Comment: I do not know. It's likely that widgets don't get garbage collected because their parents keep a reference. Why associating a variable with a command attribute isn't good enough to hold a reference, I don't know.